# BlankPage.Page1 is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to change the Opacity of a Grid located in BlankPage.xaml from another xaml page. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
 BlankPage.Page1.Opacity = 20;
```

BlankPage is my xaml page. | Page1 is the name of my Grid control.

How to change it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `BlankPage` a reference to an instance of BlankPage class?

Comment: It's probably protected right now, because this is the normal state of the controllers in c#, but there must be an option to change it, I just can't find it in Designer view. Probably I am trying to do it the wrong way. BlankPage.xaml was made entirely in Designer view. I have a button on the 2nd xaml page. I clicked twice on this button and the VS opened a xaml.cs for me. I am trying to change the opacity now. Have no Idea is this the reference to the BlankPage class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting x:FieldModifier="public" next to x:Name="Page1". I believe the default is private.

Answer (score 0):

i met similar issue earlier.

i was trying to pass data to user control and i ended up passing it as a parameter from the page and trigger it after InitializeComponent